# Accessing the Environment setting from publishable Angular Library

Tags: angular, angular7, ngrx, nrwl

I have created the a Nx based Workspace which has two shell apps ( app1 and app2). Will be reusing this CoreModule library in these two apps.

While adding Ngrx store root im getting the error in access Environment object from the library as Environments folder exists in the shell apps.

please let me know how to  inject environment object into core module such that i can do this conditional load of the module

**!environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : []**

Here is the code snippet where in i'm getting error, i have surround the line within  comments.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import {
  APP_FEATURE_KEY,
  initialState as appInitialState,
  appReducer
} from './+state/app.reducer';
import { AppEffects } from './+state/app.effects';
import { NxModule } from '@nrwl/nx';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
// <error>
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
// </error>
import { storeFreeze } from 'ngrx-store-freeze';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NxModule.forRoot(),
    StoreModule.forRoot(
      { app: appReducer },
      {
        initialState: { app: appInitialState },
        metaReducers: !environment.production ? [storeFreeze] : []
      }
    ),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects]),
    !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : []
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {
}
```

Updated:

I tried this option to inject environment , but i cannot use env in the @NgModule decorator.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule]
})
export class CoreModule {

  static forRoot(environment:any):ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule :CoreModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide : 'env',
          useValue: environment
        }
      ] } }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your project structure aliases in `path` config in your `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,  
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      ...,
      "@mainApp/*": ["app1/app/*"],
      "@secondApp/*": ["app2/app/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Suggestion(Alternate Approach): You could try to avoid creating root state in a shared module. Instead create root state in respective app modules and create feature state in shared module and import them. That way it might be more easier.Also please check, creating root store in a shared module and importing them will create one instance of the root store or two?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue, since environment files are stored at the app level by the CLI. One way around this is to have a lib dedicated to the environment for a particular app `libs/myapp/data-access-environment`. This would contain two things:

1. A type definition for the environment (`MyAppEnv`)
2. An injection token (`MYAPP_ENV_TOKEN`)

You can use the injection token to provide the value for the application. E.g. in your `app.module`:

```
provide: [ { provide: MYAPP_ENV_TOKEN, useValue: myEnv }] // import myEnv from environment.ts
```

Then in your other libs, you can inject the token and add the typing

```
constructor(@Inject(MYAPP_ENV_TOKEN) private env: MyAppEnv) {}
```

In this way you can decouple the environment from your app.

Comment: i have updated my question with options that i tried but it did not  yield what i expected.